# Save image and drawn shapes in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, image, tiff

I have a picturebox in my form and draw shapes in picturebox by MouseDown and MouseUp events. Finally, I must save image of picturebox with drawn shapes in TIFF File. I use this code:

```
Dim bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, PictureBox1.ClientRectangle)
Dim PATH = Application.StartupPath & "\TIFF\" & My.Settings.PATH & ".TIFF"
bitmap.Save(PATH, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

But the clarity and quality of the TIF image is much lower than the original image. I will link a part of the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37nt.jpg) and the [resulting TIFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcUDx.jpg) for Comparison.

All of my codes:

```
Public Class Form5
    Private firstPage As Image
    Private bmp As Bitmap
    Private NewSegment As Segment
    Private Segments As New List(Of Segment)
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        NewSegment = New Segment(e.Location, e.Location)
        Segments.Add(NewSegment)
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If NewSegment Is Nothing Then Return
        NewSegment.Point2 = e.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
        NewSegment = Nothing
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        Dim g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
        g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        For Each segment As Segment In Segments
            segment.Draw(g, Nothing)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Load("path and filename")
        bmp = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

        Using GR = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            GR.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            GR.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            GR.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            GR.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, New Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height))
        End Using
        Panel1.Controls.Add(PictureBox1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(Path, Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
    End Sub

    Private Sub zoom_in_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles zoom_in.Click
        PictureBox1.Width += Convert.ToInt32(PictureBox1.Width * 50 / 1000)
        PictureBox1.Height += Convert.ToInt32(PictureBox1.Height * 50 / 1000)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Sub

    Private Sub zoom_out_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles zoom_out.Click
        PictureBox1.Width += Convert.ToInt32(PictureBox1.Width * -50 / 1000)
        PictureBox1.Height += Convert.ToInt32(PictureBox1.Height * -50 / 1000)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Sub

End Class

Class Segment

    Private Const RADIUS As Integer = 15
    Private Shared rc_r As New Rectangle(New Point(-RADIUS, -RADIUS), New Size(RADIUS * 1.5, RADIUS * 1.5)) 'for rectangle
    Private pt1, pt2 As Point
    Private angle As Double = 0
    Private length As Double = 0
    Private Shared pen1 As New Pen(Color.Black, 1.5)
    Private Shared drawFontF As New Font("times new roman", 8, style:=FontStyle.Bold)
    Private Shared SF As StringFormat
    Public Sub New(startPoint As Point, endPoint As Point)
        Point1 = startPoint
        Point2 = endPoint
    End Sub

    Public Property Point1 As Point
        Get
            Return pt1
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            pt1 = value
            UpdateAngleAndLength()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Point2 As Point
        Get
            Return pt2
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            pt2 = value
            UpdateAngleAndLength()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub UpdateAngleAndLength()
        angle = Math.Atan2(Point2.Y - Point1.Y, Point2.X - Point1.X) * 180.0 / Math.PI
        length = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Point2.X - Point1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Point2.Y - Point1.Y, 2))
    End Sub
    Public Sub Draw(gr As System.Drawing.Graphics, R As Rectangle)

        If Point1 = Point2 Then Return
        ' save the current state of the graphics
        Dim curState As GraphicsState = gr.Save()

        ' move the origin to the start point of the line
        gr.TranslateTransform(Point1.X, Point1.Y)
        ' rotate the whole surface
        gr.RotateTransform(angle)

        ' draw the line on the x-axis
        gr.DrawLine(pen1, 0, 0, CInt(length), 0)

        gr.Restore(curState)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't use `DrawToBitmap()` for this. You are drawing with the `e.Graphics` object provided by the `Paint` event. So you just need to replace the Graphics object with one derived from a Bitmap (e.g., `dim g = Graphics.FromImage([the Bitmap])`. After that, redraw the Bitmap with what you were drawing onto the surface of the Control. Remember to call `.SetResolution()` to set the same DPI as your current UI. Then save this Bitmap (since you want to save a TIFF image, it's probably better to use the TIFF Encoder, so you can set quality and compression with dedicated `EncoderParameters`)

Comment: Excellent. but I have a new problem! If we zoom-in or zoom-out the image before drawing the shapes, the shapes will not be drawn in their exact place! maybe because don't call .SetResolution(). because I don't khow where and when I must use it.

Comment: Zooming is applying a multiplier. If you do that when drawing on a Control's surface, you can do the same with a Bitmap. Use the multiplier to also size the Bitmap -- `.SetResolution()` (belongs to the Bitmap object) is related to the DPI, not the size of the image. You call this method when your application is not DpiAware, or just partially, or when you allow / have to specify the DPI descriptor (because the image is meant to be rendered in a specific DPI context, e.g., a Printer), since it can different from the current

Comment: dear @Jimi I wanted to say that I edit my question and put the all my code after change. Please check it. thanks very much